# How to filter a dataframe by rows of another one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have two dataframes: df1:

```
 id          type
"a"      "alpha"
"a"      "alpha"
"a"      "beta"
"a"      "gamma"
```

and df2:

```
 id          type          
"a"      "alpha"         
"a"      "alpha"         
"a"      "alpha"          
"a"      "alpha"          
"a"      "beta"           
"a"      "beta"
```

for each row in df1 i want to remove single row from df2 if they have same "id" and "type". so desired result is:

```
 id          type          
"a"      "alpha"         
"a"      "alpha"          
"a"      "beta"
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collection.Counter` to subtract element of df1 from df2, then rebuild a Dataframe:

```
from collections import Counter
cols = ['id', 'type']
diff = Counter(zip(*df2[cols].T.values)) - Counter(zip(*df1[cols].T.values))
pd.DataFrame([k for k,v in diff.items() for _ in range(v)], columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
    id     type
0  "a"  "alpha"
1  "a"  "alpha"
2  "a"   "beta"
```

Edit: slightly refactoring code for modularity